# Skipping errors in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a list of file to read. I wrote a loop, like this (it is only a example). However, some of these elements are missing and I got a message error interrupting the loop.I would like to skip the error and finish the loop, with the other elements of the list.

> list<- c("ciao",
> "miao",
> "bau")
>
> ```
> for (symbols in list){
>  a <- symbols
>  b <- as.Date(symbols)
>  c <- as.numeric(symbols)
> d<- cbind(a,b,c)
> write.csv(d)
> }
> ```

As, far as I know, I could use the function try. I have already read some examples here, but they don't fit my need... or I don't know how to implement it.

Any idea to solve the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tryCatch()` for this and use the `error =` part to indicate what you want in the case of an error.

For example, in the below we can continue checking if the symbol == "bau" even after "miao" caused an error:

```r
# error before it checks all args of list
list <- c("ciao", "miao", "bau")

for (symbols in list) {
  if (symbols == "miao") stop("Er!")
  print(symbols == "bau")
}
#> [1] FALSE
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): Er!

# now it will check all args even with error
for (symbols in list) {
  tryCatch(
    expr = {
      if (symbols == "miao") stop("Er!")
      print(symbols == "bau")
    },
    error = function(e) NA
  )
}
#> [1] FALSE
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: In my case, the error is a message from R... the the file doesn't exist.  I would like to skip, and pass to the other element of the list